# Rewrite rule containing double slash not matched

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm using this rewrite rule to redirect my search requests:
`RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]*)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?search=$1&additional=$2 [L]`

This rule works fine for
`search/search/add`
but it gives me a page not found for
`search//add` (empty search)

What am I doing wrong? The regex should match:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uMlWnVTxN_LdyUWH)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes your regex will match `search//add` but problem is that `mod_rewrite` engine strips multiple slashes into single one in `RewriteRule` directive.

You can use a `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/([^/.]*)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?search=%1&additional=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there's a difference :)